# Unable to unlock screen if QuickTime was the last app open in fullscreen view

Tags: macos, screen-lock

I noticed that if I leave QuickTime open in fullscreen and then my screen is locked, I have no way to unlock it:

- Screen is completely black but for the mouse cursor.
- I can move the mouse across the screen and the attached external monitor.
- Both the external keyboard and the laptop one have no other effect than to make the system beep by each keystroke.

Is there a better way than to force power off the machine to unlock it?

Comment: Had similar issues until I updated my OS to 10.11.3. Tried updating the OS and regular disk aid trick ?

Answer (score 1):

command+option+esc, than force quit QT Player